# Bug in ARKit 3D Motion Body Motion Capture

Tags: swift, 3d, arkit, pose-estimation, arbodyanchor

[This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/capturing_body_motion_in_3d) sample code for  3D motion capture has a bug in it. The feet ankles and feet of virtual object do not overlay accurately on the person. The feet always face downwards, refer to the attached image. Any thoughts on how it can be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying the same with Unity's ARFoundation. From my observation, the foot detection was fine before I upgraded my iPhone 13 to iOS 16. On further reading , it seems iOS 16 comes with ARKit 6 and the bug might be related to it.

Edit 01 - Downgraded my phone back to iOS 15.7 and the feet went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ARFoundation 5.1.0-pre.4 the bug is fixed in this Version and everything else seems to run without problems.